# PostgreSQL View Query Times Exponential with Integer Array Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL view (`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW table_view AS ...`) that has 20 columns, with a mixture of text, integer, boolean and integer array fields. In total, there are nine columns that are integer arrays.

This view works very well the overwhelming majority of the time. However, when a row shows up with ~50 total values within the integer array, the query slows to a crawl. These columns are not being queried against, they are simply just part of the resultset, but the magnitude of the query goes from ~250ms to ~7s if any rows are returned that contain the high number of integer array values.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT                   
    "table_view"."id", -- integer
    "table_view"."start", -- date with tz
    "table_view"."end", -- date with tz
    "table_view"."a_id", -- integer
    "table_view"."c_id", -- integer
    "table_view"."generator_id", -- integer
    "table_view"."ci_id", -- integer
    "table_view"."kind", -- integer
    "table_view"."hidden", -- boolean
    "table_view"."is_done", -- integer
    "table_view"."title", -- text
    "table_view"."c_type", -- integer
    "table_view"."ci_title", -- integer
    "table_view"."status", -- text
    "table_view"."cs", -- integer array
    "table_view"."cts",  -- integer array
    "table_view"."ts", -- integer array
    "table_view"."tas", -- integer array
    "table_view"."bs", -- integer array
    "table_view"."ms", -- integer array
    "table_view"."pcs", -- integer array
    "table_view"."pts", -- integer array
    "table_view"."ks" -- integer array
FROM
    "table_view"
WHERE (
    "table_view"."a_id" = 3289
    AND (
        "table_view"."cs" && ARRAY[28890, 21166, 28891, 29581, 29583, 22378, 22380, 22733, 28924, 28925, 28926, 28927, 28478, 41014]::integer[]
        OR "table_view"."ms" && ARRAY[11125]::integer[]
    ) AND NOT (
        "table_view"."hidden" = true
        AND NOT (
            "table_view"."ms" && ARRAY[11125]::integer[]
        )
    ) AND "table_view"."end" >= '2019-02-03T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz
    AND "table_view"."start" < '2019-04-15T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz
);
```

If none of the rows have a sum of integer array values ~> 50, the query time is ~50ms to 250ms.

`Time: 50.417 ms`

However, if one or more of the rows have a sum of integer array values <~ 50, the query time is ~6.5s to 7s.

`Time: 6737.154 ms`

I have obfuscated some of the columns names from this query, but that shouldn't impact the debugging of this issue. I'm beating myself up over this. Nothing I am researching online mentioned anything about column length being an issue in the resulting query.

Here is the output of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the "bad" query:

```
 Subquery Scan on table_view  (cost=173.16..173.29 rows=1 width=436) (actual time=648.470..800.577 rows=60 loops=1)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=173.16..173.28 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=648.468..800.552 rows=60 loops=1)
         Group Key: dhci.id, wfciwf.id, dutm.account_id
         Filter: (((array_append('{}'::integer[], dhci.cid) && '{28890,21166,28891,29581,29583,22378,22380,22733,28924,28925,28926,28927,28478,41014}'::integer[]) OR (array_agg(DISTIN
CT dhamti.member_id) && '{11125}'::integer[])) AND ((NOT dhci.hidden) OR (array_agg(DISTINCT dhamti.member_id) && '{11125}'::integer[])))
         ->  Sort  (cost=173.16..173.17 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=647.727..685.155 rows=172000 loops=1)
               Sort Key: dhci.id, wfciwf.id, dutm.account_id
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 16392kB
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=68.45..173.15 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=1.033..478.844 rows=172000 loops=1)
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=68.16..171.71 rows=1 width=99) (actual time=1.017..308.168 rows=172000 loops=1)
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=67.87..170.20 rows=1 width=95) (actual time=0.997..126.331 rows=172000 loops=1)
                                 ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=67.58..168.77 rows=1 width=91) (actual time=0.978..26.478 rows=33400 loops=1)
                                       ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=67.16..165.68 rows=1 width=87) (actual time=0.960..4.997 rows=3700 loops=1)
                                             ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=66.73..162.71 rows=1 width=83) (actual time=0.949..2.572 rows=410 loops=1)
                                                   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=66.44..161.59 rows=1 width=79) (actual time=0.939..2.121 rows=60 loops=1)
                                                         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=66.02..154.64 rows=1 width=75) (actual time=0.926..1.818 rows=60 loops=1)
                                                               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=65.59..148.07 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.902..1.446 rows=60 loops=1)
                                                                     ->  Index Scan using dutm_8a089c2a on dutm  (cost=0.29..9.40 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.028 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: (account_id = 3289)
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dhci  (cost=65.31..69.33 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.137..0.148 rows=7 loops=9)
                                                                           Recheck Cond: ((owner_member_id = dutm.id) AND (deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (deadline >= '2019-02-03 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (deadline < '2019-04-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                                                           Heap Blocks: exact=36
                                                                           ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=65.31..65.31 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.135..0.135 rows=0 loops=9)
                                                                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dhci_9adb17cb  (cost=0.00..5.79 rows=182 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=167 loops=9)
                                                                                       Index Cond: (owner_member_id = dutm.id)
                                                                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dhci_deadline_ba8bd3addbfe7dc_uniq  (cost=0.00..58.66 rows=2419 width=0) (actual time=0.263..0.263 rows=1727 loops=3)
                                                                                       Index Cond: ((deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (deadline >= '2019-02-03 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (deadline < '2019-04-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                                               ->  Index Scan using wfciwf_pkey on wfciwf  (cost=0.42..6.55 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=60)
                                                                     Index Cond: (id = dhci.workflow_state_id)
                                                                     Filter: (((current_status)::text <> 'killed'::text) AND ((current_status)::text <> 'parked'::text))
                                                         ->  Index Scan using dhamti_d7bbcb82 on dhamti  (cost=0.42..6.93 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=60)
                                                               Index Cond: (content_item_id = dhci.id)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using dhcibs_6123fe8a on dhcibs  (cost=0.29..1.10 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=7 loops=60)
                                                         Index Cond: (ciid = dhci.id)
                                             ->  Index Scan using dhcit_6123fe8a on dhcit  (cost=0.42..2.95 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.004 rows=9 loops=410)
                                                   Index Cond: (ciid = dhci.id)
                                       ->  Index Scan using ghcita_6123fe8a on ghcita  (cost=0.42..3.07 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=9 loops=3700)
                                             Index Cond: (ciid = dhci.id)
                                 ->  Index Scan using dhcipc_6123fe8a on dhcipc  (cost=0.29..1.41 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=5 loops=33400)
                                       Index Cond: (ciid = dhci.id)
                           ->  Index Scan using dhcipt_6123fe8a on dhcipt  (cost=0.29..1.49 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=172000)
                                 Index Cond: (ciid = dhci.id)
                     ->  Index Scan using dhcik_6123fe8a on dhcik  (cost=0.29..1.41 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=172000)
                           Index Cond: (ciid = dhci.id)
 Planning time: 8.219 ms
 Execution time: 804.161 ms
(45 rows)
```

Comment: Of course after I submit this question I had a small epiphany; could it be that the underlying query of the SQL view is inefficient?

Comment: Maybe. Do an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the slow vs fast query and post the results.

Comment: Will do, but it will take me a few minutes to obfuscate table names.

Comment: @eurotrash I have added the explain analyze to the original question.